# Saving Python code in Anaconda

Tags: save, anaconda

I am having problems saving the Python code in Anaconda. I write code, Go to File Save as the file is saved but when I open it is empty, no code. I read that IDLE does not save code, it erases it when I close Anaconda.

I have searched in books, youtube tutorials and nothing. I could not find this topic. I can find advanced topics, but this one no.

Thank you for your help!

Best,

Tiberiu

Answer (score 0):

This somewhat depends on what OS you are on. I can speak from my experience. I would highly recommend using [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) as an IDE.

But more fundamentally than that, lets talk about saving files. On Mac OS X or Ubuntu 14.04 (or the like), lets say you want to create a python file. One way is to do the following in a terminal:

```
nano hello.py
```

This opens up a text editor whose instructions for use are on the bottom of the screen. On Windows you could do:

```
notepad hello.py
```

In both cases you then write your code. Lets say the content was:

```
#content of hello.py
print "Hello World!"
```

Then you need to save the file and execute it with Python. 
Which brings us to the Python issue.

Once you have installed Anaconda, and assuming that there are no other Python installations on your computer. The Anaconda Python should be the active Python on system.

Suffice to say that there are other ways of saving files rather than using IDLE. Personally I have found PyCharm to be a much better IDE for writing Python code.

To address the IDLE issue more directly once you type in the terminal/command prompt `idle` to launch an IDLE session, likely the IDLE Shell will open up. Perhaps you are trying to save this, in which case you will only save the Shell session.

So go to File - New - Save. This should work without any problem (it does on my system). Good luck! Hope this helps.